# Add DCMTK library and compile for Xcode 12.4+

Tags: xcode, compilation, xcode12, dcmtk

I'm trying to install and add the **DCMTK** library to my Xcode project.  The library can be found here https://dicom.offis.de/training.php.en

I ran the command to install via home-brew `brew install dcmtk` but I'm not sure how to add the library and start using it in my project.  I have no idea how to add this to my dependencies in Xcode.  I managed to successfully compile Horus which uses the framework, but it gives a BAD_ACCESS error after running and I'm not sure how they managed to get it to work? It appears they run it as a build target that then runs CMake behind the scenes? I'm not familiar with this style of doing it.  This is the link to the Horos Project that uses the library in the way I need to (https://github.com/horosproject/horos)

I see many questions regarding this with older versions of Xcode that no longer compile with the newest Xcode which is why I'm asking this question here.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to ask this in the [dcmtk forum](https://forum.dcmtk.org/)?

Comment: I have not yet, I'll try asking here to see if anyone can help, thanks for the idea.

Comment: There forum is invite only so I sent request to get on as a user, in the meantime I'm still learning how to use this.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not, at least not with the newest xCode, although I have not tried recently anytime soon.